# Python module implemented like a package

Tags: python, module, pydoc

I have an application containing a package, thus:

```
* fruits/
  | citrus/
  | | __init__.py
  | | oranges.py
  | | mandarins.py
  | | satsumas.py
  | | ... etc
```

The Python files under `fruits/citrus/` contain definitions of about 300 subclasses of `fruits.citrus.Citrus`.

They live in separate files like this only for administrative reasons. Nobody should know or care about `fruits.citrus.mandarins` etc unless they're working on the `fruits.citrus` package. To put it another way, I would like this package to pretend it's a module.

I have tried putting this in `__init__.py`:

```
from fruits.citrus.oranges import *
from fruits.citrus.mandarins import *
from fruits.citrus.satsumas import *
[...]

g = list(globals().items())

__all__ = list([
    name for name, value in g
    if value.__class__==type and
    issubclass(value, Citrus)
    ])
```

This sort of works, in that you can see `fruits.citrus.Tangerine`. But pydoc and sphinx still list `oranges`, `mandarins`, etc as package contents. And `Tangerine` is both at `fruits.citrus.Tangerine` *and* at `fruits.citrus.mandarins.Tangerine`, so things are even more complicated than when I started.

There has to be a way to do this, but everything I tried has been a lemon. Help?

Comment: Can you specify _why_ you are attempting to do this? does `Tangerine` exist twice or is it just linked in the init.py file? Copying a file to exist twice is very bad practice.

Comment: It was just linked in the __init__.py file.

I was trying to think of how to get an autodoc program to ignore this, but I decided in the end not to use the autodoc program!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there isn't a good way, but that's all right.

I was trying to use an autodoc program to document a codebase, and it kept listing all these classes twice. The answer in the end was just to specify the classes by hand!

Answer (score 2):

can you tell if that helps hiding those submodules:

```
from .mandarins import *
from .oranges import *

del globals()['mandarins']
del globals()['oranges']
```